# Ode does not solve the equations properly

Tags: r, bioinformatics, modeling, ode

I'm completely new with R and equation solving and stuff like that, yet I have a university task which involves differential equations and R, and I cannot do it properly at all...

````
```{r}
library(deSolve)
```

```{r}
model9 <- function(t, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(y, parms), {
  Ptbs1 <- 1/(1+(TALe/Kd1)) 
  #Ptbs8 <- 1/(1+(TALe/Kd8))  

  dy    <- numeric(6)
  dy[1] <- a.tale*Pbad - gamma.mRNA*RiboTALe.mRNA 
  dy[2] <- kon*RiboTALe.mRNA*theo-koff*RiboTALe.mRNAw 
  dy[3] <- b.tale*RiboTALe.mRNAw - gamma.protein*TALe 
  dy[4] <- a.gfp*Ptet*Ptbs1-gamma.mRNA*GFP.mRNA # CONSIDERAR PTBS8 LUEGO
  # dy[4] <- a.gfp*Ptet*Ptbs8-gamma.mRNA*GFP.mRNA 
  dy[5] <- b.gfp*GFP.mRNA-gamma.protein*GFP.int-beta*GFP.int 
  dy[6] <- beta*GFP.int-gamma.lvatag*GFP 

  list(dy)})
}
```

# Incognitas

```{r}
y <- c(RiboTALe.mRNA = 0,
  RiboTALe.mRNAw = 0,
  GFP.mRNA = 0,
  GFP.int = 0,
  GFP = 0,
  TALe = 0)
```

# Parametros

```{r}
parms <- c(Cobad <- (10*10^{-6}),
  Cotet <- (10*10^{-6}),
  nbad <- 2.8,
  ntet  <- 1,
  Kdbad <- (9*10^{-5}),
  Kdtet <- (3.83*10^{-9}),

  K1bad <- 9*10^{-3},
  K1tet <- 350,
  Kd1 <- 240*10^{-9},
  Kd8 <- 1.3*10^{-9},
  K2bad <- 37.5/(10*10^{-6}),
  K3bad <- 3.4/(10*10^{-6}),
  K2tet <- 160/(10*10^{-6}),

  koff <- 0.3*10^{-9},
  kon <- 1*10^{-3},

  gamma.lvatag  <- 2*10^{-4},
  gamma.mRNA <- 1.7*10^{-3},
  gamma.protein <- 5.6*10^{-5},
  a.gfp <- 0.03,
  a.tale  <- 0.01,
  b.gfp <- 0.06,
  b.tale <- 0.02,
  beta <- 6.7*10^{-4},
  Lbad <- 0.01,
  Ltet <- 25,
  theo <- 0,
  C1 <- (Cobad*(Lbad^nbad))/((Kdbad^nbad)+(Lbad^nbad)),
  C2 <- (Cotet*(Ltet^ntet))/((Kdtet^ntet)+(Ltet^ntet)),
  Cf1 <-  Cobad - C1,
  Cf2 <-  Cotet - C2,
  Pbad <- (K1bad+K2bad*C1)/(1+K1bad+K2bad*C1+K3bad*Cf1),
  Ptet <- K1tet/(1+K1tet+2*K2tet*Cf2+(K2tet^2)*(Cf2^2)) )
```

```{r}
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 3600, by = 1)
```

```{r}
out <- ode(y = y, times = times, func = model9, parms = parms)
```

```{r}
plot(out)
```
````

This is a modeling of a biological system involving different molecules, RNA, etc. 
The idea is that, when the parameter "theo" is equal to zero, there should be no variation of TALe, yet if you plot all of this, TALe increases.

On the other hand, if "theo" is more than 0, I get an error message:

> Error in lsoda(y, times, func, parms, ...) : illegal input detected
>   before taking any integration steps - see written message

The idea is to get the results as in here: http://2013.igem.org/Team:UC_Davis/Modeling, but I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: When you define a named list or vector, use `=`, not `<-`. In addition to making a named vector called `parms`, you're also making each element a separate variable in the global environment. This raises the possibility of all kinds of namespace collisions with unpredictable effects. Try fixing that and see it the problem is the same